# Everything starting with android: has some error or warning in xml files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-view

My project is building properly , but i am not able to see preview of UI and all the attributes starting with android: are either in red and says cannot resolve symbol. And also there is an error that says

> One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height
>   attributes. These are required in most layouts.

But i have checked all xml files manually and there is no layout without height and width. Please suggest me some thing.

P.S.
I have tried rebuild, clean and invalidate cache and restart.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F9FE"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="Help"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_close_help"
            android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_close" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_help_call"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_call" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:text="@string/for_any_queries_kindly_call_us_on"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="8000 1111 1111"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_make_call"
                style="@style/RobotoMediumStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FAFAFA"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="Call"
                android:textColor="@color/text_green"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_help_call"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_help" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:text="@string/you_can_also_contact_via_email"
                android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="info@winds.com"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_make_mail"
                style="@style/RobotoMediumStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FAFAFA"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="@string/contact_us_email"
                android:textColor="@color/text_green"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_nav_back</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_nav_back</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/ic_close_white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="OtpFieldStyle">
        <item name="android:maxLength">2</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
        <item name="android:cursorVisible">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SignUpFieldStyle" parent="RobotoMediumStyle">
        <!--<item name="android:layout_marginRight">50dp</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">50dp</item>-->

        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/warm_grey</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    </style>


    <style name="RobotoBlackStyle">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_fontFamily_black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_two</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RobotoLightStyle">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_fontFamily_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RobotoMediumStyle">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_fontFamily_medium</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/row_text_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/rating_star_color</item>
    </style>


    <style name="RatingBarSmall" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/rating_transparent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/rating_star_golden</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DashBoardImage" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DashBoardText" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal|bottom</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">20dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DashBoardCard" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="tabTheam" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_color_selector</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>


    <style name="button_style">
        <item name="android:height">@dimen/_40sdp</item>
        <item name="android:width">@dimen/pw_large_margin</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_button_selector</item>
    </style>


    <style name="noInputEdittext" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/peacock_blue</item>
        <item name="android:drawableEnd">@drawable/img_down_blue</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">false</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">none</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_btn_radio</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: how many layout(xml file) do you have?and inside everyone, how many control do you have? check all controls in layout(xml files) carefully

Comment: went throught all xml files, made sure each of them has height and width, and changed ?actionBarSize to ?android:attr/actionBarSize also. Still its giving errors. Now its giving new error : Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Answer (score 0):

Add the following namespace into your parent item :-

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: its already there, infact in some places there are two of them :  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Sure, i thought to, but the question is How many? this error is there in all of them. I'll add 1 of them and share my style file too. 1 min please.

Comment: Check it now please.

Comment: Try syncing the project. If it doesn't work, try the good old fashioned System Restart.

Comment: Tried syncing also, Hoping system restart will work. Gimme me few minutes.

Comment: Check your styles file. Maybe something in there is causing the problem